# SBT packager war

Tags: sbt, war

As per SBT documentation (version 1.2.x)
-> https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Artifacts.html
there is a `packagerWar` task.

```
// disable .jar publishing 
publishArtifact in (Compile, packageBin) := false 

// create an Artifact for publishing the .war file 
artifact in (Compile, packageWar) := {
  val previous: Artifact = (artifact in (Compile, packageWar)).value
  previous.withType("war").withExtension("war")
} 

// add the .war file to what gets published 
addArtifact(artifact in (Compile, packageWar), packageWar)
```

The packageWar key does not exist in SBT though. Is it a mistake in SBT documentation or is my understanding of the way it should be used incorrect?